# onBlur fires before file was uploaded (RHF + MUI)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

it seems like I've confused myself and I can't find the error. When I upload a file, errors from RHF are triggered before I actually upload the file. This happens right after I click on the field itself. After the file is uploaded, the onBlur event doesn't trigger automatically, and I need to manually trigger it by changing the focus from the field to any other place. This is likely because all RHF events were fired when I clicked on the field for the first time, and they don't trigger on file upload itself. However, I can't find the bug. Thanks in advance for any ideas.
Code below

**FileInput.tsx**

```
import { FileUploadOutlined } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { SxProps, Theme } from '@mui/material';
import { ChangeEvent, ForwardedRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { IconButton } from '../IconButton';
import { TextField, TextFieldProps } from '../TextField';

interface FileInputRef {
  fileInput: HTMLInputElement | null;
  textInput: HTMLInputElement | null;
  files: FileList | null;
}

export type FileInputProps = {
  multiple?: boolean;
  setControlledValue?: (file: File) => void;
  acceptedFiles?: string;
  uploadButtonSxProps?: SxProps<Theme>;
} & Omit<TextFieldProps, 'ref'>;

export const FileInput = forwardRef(
  (
    { multiple, size = 'small', setControlledValue, acceptedFiles, uploadButtonSxProps, ...props }: FileInputProps,
    ref: ForwardedRef<FileInputRef>
  ) => {
    const fileRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const textRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.value ? (props.value as File).name : '');
    const [files, setFiles] = useState<FileList | null>(null);

    const onFileChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if (e.target.files?.length) {
        setFiles(e.target.files);
        setValue(e.target.files.length > 1 ? 'multiple' : e.target.files[0]?.name);
        setControlledValue && setControlledValue(e.target.files[0]);
      }
    };

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
      get fileInput() {
        return fileRef.current;
      },
      get textInput() {
        return textRef.current;
      },
      get files() {
        return files;
      },
    }));

    const onClick = () => fileRef.current?.click();

    return (
      <TextField
        {...props}
        size={size}
        inputRef={textRef}
        value={value}
        onClick={onClick}
        InputLabelProps={{
          shrink: value !== '',
        }}
        InputProps={{
          readOnly: true,
          sx: { padding: 0 },
          inputProps: {
            sx: { cursor: 'pointer', textOverflow: 'ellipsis' },
          },
          endAdornment: (
            <>
              <input
                type="file"
                accept={acceptedFiles}
                ref={fileRef}
                multiple={multiple}
                onChange={onFileChange}
                style={{ display: 'none' }}
              />
              <IconButton sx={uploadButtonSxProps}>
                <FileUploadOutlined />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          ),
        }}
      />
    );
  }
);

export default FileInput;
```

**FileInputController.tsx**

```
import { Control, Controller, FieldValues, Path } from 'react-hook-form';
import { FileInput, FileInputProps } from '@customlib';

type FileInputControllerProps<T extends FieldValues> = {
  name: Path<T>;
  control: Control<T, object>;
} & Omit<FileInputProps, 'name'>;

export function FileInputController<T extends FieldValues>({ name, control, ...rest }: FileInputControllerProps<T>) {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => <FileInput variant="outlined" {...field} {...rest} />}
    />
  );
}

export default FileInputController;
```

**FileInput implementation:**

```
    <FileInputController
      name={'file'}
      control={control}
      label={t('documentFile')}
      error={errors.file != null}
      helperText={
        <Trans
          t={tValidatations}
          i18nKey={errors.file?.message}
          values={{ fileTypes: [...new Set(allowedDocumentExtensions.split(','))] }}
        />
      }
      setControlledValue={handleUploadFile}
      acceptedFiles={allowedDocumentExtensions}
      uploadButtonSxProps={uploadButtonSxProps}
      sx={fieldWidth}
    />
```

**handleUploadFile(if needed):**

```
  const handleUploadFile = (file: File) => {
    setValue(`file`, file, { shouldValidate: true }); //RHF setValue
    setValue('fileName', file.name); //RHF setValue
    getValues().sameAsFileName && setValue('documentName', file.name); //RHF getValues
    trigger(['file', 'fileName', 'documentName']); // RHF - quick&dirty solution, i want to avoid it
  };
```